# Is there a rules-based way to make a dragon player character?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, dragons

I got to thinking Wouldn't it be cool to play some kind of proper dragon with Character levels?

So I wonder, is there a rules-based way to make a dragon player character?

My guess is that this is one of those DM fiat sort of things, and that it could be unbalanced. But is there any way?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but some related questions are: [Can I have a dragon player character in D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116070/43856), [Can I create a character that by leveling comes closer to a dragon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121511/43856), [How can a PC become more draconic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105777/43856)

Comment: Now that it's been cleared up with comments and edits, I think this is probably a duplicate of [Can I have a dragon player character in D&D 5e?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116070). If what you're asking is different, you can [edit] this question to include the parts that make it obviously a different question.

Answer (score 3):

## A metallic dragon's Change Shape doesn't give them class features

> The dragon magically polymorphs into a humanoid or beast that has a challenge rating no higher than its own, or back into its true form... Its statistics and capabilities are... replaced by those of the new form, **except any class features** or legendary actions of that form.
>
> [**emphasis** mine]

### However...

A GM can add class features to any monster using the rules for Creating a Monster in the Dungeon Master's Guide

See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53857/41726) for more details on this option.

Comment: I read the question as about making a PC dragon (and it's conflating “having class levels” with “being a player character”). If you see that too, it may be worth addressing directly.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I didn't read it that way but I can see that as an interpretation. I'll ask a clarifying comment